# MongoBD SSIS C# driver - вопрос о вложенных документах

Tags: c#, mongodb

Очень нужна помощь с использованием С# драйвера для SSIS 2013.

Я использую MongoDB только как источник данных SSIS, чтобы загрузить данные в таблицу SQL Server, и с С# драйвером работаю совсем недавно.

До сих пор не приходилось встречаться с вложенными документами.
Обычно в C# Script task я создаю переменную и затем использую ее в курсоре:

```
var query = Query.And(Query.Or(Query.GT("CreatedOn",maxUpdatedOnBSON), Query.GT("UpdatedOn", maxUpdatedOnBSON)), 
        Query.Or(Query.LT("CreatedOn", cutoffDate), Query.LT("UpdatedOn", cutoffDate)),Query.In("TestType", testTypes) );  

MongoCursor<BsonDocument> toReturn = collection.Find(query);
```

Что нужно делать с вложенными документами?

Javascript ниже работает в MongoDB.
Он выбирает только документы, отвечающие критериям в `$match`, и `$unwind` позволяет получить отдельный ряд для каждого `Items`, дополненный элементами заголовка.

```
db.Test.aggregate( [ 
{ $unwind : { path: "$Items",includeArrayIndex: "arrayIndex"} } ,
{ $match:  { $and: [
        {$or: [ { CreatedOn: { $gt: ISODate("2015-11-22T00:00:00Z")} }, {UpdatedOn: { $gt: ISODate("2015-11-22T00:00:00Z") } } ] },
        {$or: [ { CreatedOn: { $lt: ISODate("2016-05-09T00:00:00Z")} }, {UpdatedOn: { $lt: ISODate("2016-05-09T00:00:00Z") } } ] }
                   ] }
 }] )
```

Как "перевести" этот код для использования в С# task?